# Restore emails with Time Machine

Tags: time-machine, email

How do you restore emails from a Time Machine backup?  I am uncertain of how to use Time Machine back up to restore emails from my Google folders.

Answer (score 1):

Open Mail, then a Time Machine backup (click System Preferences > Time Machine > Enter Time Machine) and browse the backups of your emails, scrolling up and down to "travel through time".

If you find a message that you want to restore, you can drag just a single message or a set of emails onto your desktop for import. Additionally, you can export an entire folder by right-clicking the folder and clicking "Export".

Answer (score 0):

Open Mail, then open Time Machine. Providing the backup disk is available, Time Machine will open and allow you to find deleted emails available for restoration.